# How to disable showing default Axis2 services (https://localhost:8243/services/Version?wsdl) in WSO2 API manager 3.2.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-gateway, axis2c

I already disabled service listing Axis2 services that are deployed in the WSO2 API Manager by adding the following configuration to the deployment.toml of the WSO2 APIM Pack:

```
[n_http]
'http.block_service_list'=true
```

but I also want to block access and disable showing all deployed services too like Version?wsdl , echo, and other default services through gateway.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the Axis2 services (`.aar` files) from the directory `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/axis2services`